# Bash Shell Script :: Send STD-OUT in Real Time?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, tcp, stdout

At my job, my team and I (we are five people) use a Java program for everyday work.  Rather than require everyone to install Java and run the programs on their laptops, I set up a little VM, put the Java code on that, then built a primitive little webpage as an interface.  When a colleague pushes a "RUN CODE" button on the webpage, the webpage runs a simple bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/java/code
runJavaCode.exe > $OUTPUTFILE
echo "Finished running the program!  Output is...\n"
echo "$OUTPUTFILE"
echo "End of script."
```

This is all laughably clunky, but it serves our purposes.

Okay, here's the problem:  Lately the Java code has needed longer than two minutes to finish its calculations.  Its working properly, I'm not concerned about the correctness of the code.  But my colleagues are discovering that their web browsers are timing out while they wait for output from the shell script.  The browsers give up before the Java code completes.

So I need some solution to keep the TCP session between browser and script alive to buy more time for the code.  But how?

One solution that occurred to me was this:  The Java code is continuously printing to STD_OUT as it operates.  The shell script collects that output into `$OUTPUTFILE`, then `echo`'s it only the Java code is finished.  But couldn't there be some way for the shell script to feed the Java Code output back to the user in real time?  That would solve my problem.

FYI:  My VM is Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).  I'm running Apache2 ver 2.4.52 as the webserver, and my bash version is 5.1.16(1).

Comment: @markp-fuso  Thanks Mark.  I tried `tee` but there's something about my HTML that still isn't displaying the STD_OUT from the shell script in real time.  I'm not sure what, but I think I'll need to make a new post to refocus on HTML.  That said, I think your solution solves the problem on the shell script end, so if you write your comment up as a solution, I'll give you the credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the buffering has something to do. Does your Java code generate much output in a steady rate? Try to use an unbuffered output to make sure that the output is being feed immediately as generated.

Comment: @Poshi Thanks Poshi.  Interesting.  My Java code spits out an STD_OUT message every second or so on average.  I hadn't thought about the output rate.  When you say "use an unbuffered output" you mean make sure the Java code sends STD_OUT to an unbuffered output queue?  Thanks

Comment: Buffers can be "large", like 64KiB. A message per second during 2 minutes are 120 messages. If each message is 80 chars long, we are talking about 80*120=9600B, less than 10KiB. Chances are that all the output is buffered and only printed at program exit.
When I say that you should use an unbuffered output I mean that you must make sure that the output is not kept in a buffer, but flushed after every write. You can flush the stream every time, or you can use an unbuffered stream. There are several ways to achieve that, it's up to you to choose the best one for your issue.

Comment: @Poshi Hmmm, thank you.  You've given me a lot to think about.  When I run the Java code manually, the code spits out about 1 message/second to STD_OUT.  The question is how to instruct the shell script to `echo` those messages in real time.  It occurred to me that this may be an issue with my HTML, not the shell script.  Thank you!

Comment: my html coding skills are very limited so fwiw ... most 'simple' web pages are static in nature, requiring a user to refresh the page to pick up new info (eg, new stdout generated by OP's java program); sure, there are web pages that can dynamically 'refresh' themselves but that's going to require a bit more 'advanced' (html) coding

Comment: @markp-fuso Dang it.  Thanks, Mark.  That wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but its very valuable information nonetheless!  Thanks for writing.  I'm off to Google on HTML coding...

Comment: `nohup` would be good choice in this case. `nohup runJavaCode.exe &` and later you can do `tail -f nohup.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
runJavaCode.exe | tee $OUTPUTFILE
```

**NOTES:**

- a copy of the java program output is written to `$OUTPUTFILE` while the output is also sent to stdout
- I have no idea how that continual stream of output will be handled by your particular web page (ie, the web page will likely need to be coded in such a way to automagically 'refresh' based on a push of new data - the java program's stdout stream)